# Generate new variable from values per group

Tags: stata

I have calculated in Stata the percentage observations per group, year, and category in a new variable.

| group | year | category | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020 | 1 | 0.4 |
| A | 2020 | 1 | 0.4 |
| A | 2020 | 2 | 0.6 |
| A | 2020 | 2 | 0.6 |
| A | 2020 | 2 | 0.6 |
| B | 2020 | 1 | 0.67 |
| B | 2020 | 1 | 0.67 |
| B | 2020 | 2 | 0.33 |

Now I want to have these percentages (per group, year, and category) in separate variables per category.
So the results should look like this:

| group | year | category | percentage | cat1 | cat2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020 | 1 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| A | 2020 | 1 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| A | 2020 | 2 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| A | 2020 | 2 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| A | 2020 | 2 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| B | 2020 | 1 | 0.67 | 0.67 | 0.33 |
| B | 2020 | 1 | 0.67 | 0.67 | 0.33 |
| B | 2020 | 2 | 0.33 | 0.67 | 0.33 |

So code-wise I did the following:

```
bysort group year category: gen cat_obs = _N 
bysort group year : gen sum_GY_obs = _N
gen mean = cat_obs / sum_GY_obs

foreach i of num 1/2 { 
    gen cat_`i'= mean if cat==`i'
}
```

Comment: The term _column_ although understandable from elsewhere,  corresponds to the term _variable_ in Stata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call your calculated results *proportions* or *fractions* (adding to 1), not *percentages* (adding to 100). As a proportion is (or can be considered as) the mean of an indicator variable, itself the result of evaluating a true or false expression, this is one way to do it:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str6 group int year byte category double percentage
"A" 2020 1  .4
"A" 2020 1  .4
"A" 2020 2  .6
"A" 2020 2  .6
"A" 2020 2  .6
"B" 2020 1 .67
"B" 2020 1 .67
"B" 2020 2 .33
end

bysort group year category: gen num = _N
bysort group year: gen den = _N

gen prop = num / den 


forval j = 1/2 { 
    egen cat`j' = mean(category == `j'), by(group year) 
} 

list 

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | group   year   category   percen~e   num   den       prop       cat1       cat2 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     A   2020          1         .4     2     5         .4         .4         .6 |
  2. |     A   2020          1         .4     2     5         .4         .4         .6 |
  3. |     A   2020          2         .6     3     5         .6         .4         .6 |
  4. |     A   2020          2         .6     3     5         .6         .4         .6 |
  5. |     A   2020          2         .6     3     5         .6         .4         .6 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |     B   2020          1        .67     2     3   .6666667   .6666667   .3333333 |
  7. |     B   2020          1        .67     2     3   .6666667   .6666667   .3333333 |
  8. |     B   2020          2        .33     1     3   .3333333   .6666667   .3333333 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```